# ListView is not working in new ADF Mobile patch

Tags: java, oracle-adf, oracle-adf-mobile

I have a issue in the component list view.
After updating, It shows the following error with EL expression: in the component “list view” show error “can not find property row” in the amx pages.
Before that its working fine with previous versions.

Code amx file:

```
<amx:popup id="p1" animation="slideUp" autoDismiss="false">
    <amx:outputText value="Did you mean?" id="ot31" inlineStyle="font-weight:bold; font-size:large;"/>
    <amx:listView var="row" value="#{pageFlowScope.serviceRequestHelper.locations}" id="lv1"
                  inlineStyle="height:300px;" >
        <amx:listItem id="li1">
            <amx:outputText value="#{row.address}" id="ot41"/>
            <amx:setPropertyListener id="spl1" from="#{row}" type="action" to="#{pageFlowScope.serviceRequestHelper.serviceRequest.locationInfo}"/>
            <amx:actionListener id="al2" binding="#{pageFlowScope.serviceRequestHelper.onLocationSelected}"/>
            <amx:closePopupBehavior id="cpb2" popupId="p1" type="action"/>
        </amx:listItem>
    </amx:listView>
    <amx:panelGroupLayout id="panelGroupLayout2"  layout="horizontal" halign="center">
        <amx:commandButton text="Cancel" id="cb4" >
            <amx:closePopupBehavior id="cpb1" popupId="p1"/>
        </amx:commandButton>
    </amx:panelGroupLayout>
</amx:popup>
```

Additional information:

Oracle IDE 11.1.2.4.39.64.64

Xcode 5.1

Java 1.6.0_51

For Reference

[Oracle ADF Mobile #{row.index} is Not Supported After Installing Upgrade Patch](http://oracleformsinfo.wordpress.com/2013/10/10/oracle-adf-mobile-row-index-is-not-supported-after-installing-upgrade-patch/#comment-2279%5d)

Any idea regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

This is bug which has been fixed in the latest drop. Try upgrading your extension version. If you have access to bug db, you should be able to get the exact version where this has been fixed.

Arun

Comment: Arun, Thanks for replying but I am using latest version of Oracle IDE.

Comment: Check if your ADF Mobile extension version is the latest